# Entity Framework: Validate and save data in single SQL transaction

Tags: entity-framework

We are using Entity Framework for our data layer.

For certain validations we need access to entities that may still be in the DB. We want it make sure that the data in question doesn’t change so we wrap the save (and validation in a transaction)

Starting an transaction on the Context’s Database.Connection throws when SaveChanges() is called.

So we use an transaction scope in an override of SaveChanges(). Stripped of error handling etc. it looks like this:

```
...
using (scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))
{
    countSaves = base.SaveChanges();
    scope.Complete();
 }
 return countSaves;
 ...
```

To make the DbContext available for validations it is placed in the Items dictionary of the ValidateEntity method.

We have a custom validation attribute like so:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class CodeListAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
   protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext context)
   {
        MyDbContext  model = (MyDbContext)context.Items["model"];
        IList<Code> validCodes = model.Codes.Where(…).ToList();
        …

      }

      ...

}
```

The read of the model.Codes  gives a “System.Data.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open” which in turn is caused by the fact, that EF tries to turn my transaction in to a distributed transaction using the MSDTC.
How can I get only a single SQL Server transaction for my validations and save?

Comment: _We want it make sure that the data in question doesn’t change_ Do you mean the data you read for validation? You won't achieve that by the default isolation level of a transaction scope. Can't you rely on optimistic concurrency in stead of this complex scenario?

Comment: no I can't rely on optimistic concurrency as the read data during validation is not changed and not written to the database. A SQL transaction with serializable transaction level would be the ultimate guarantee, but repeatable read would be good enough for our scenario.

Comment: Is the context instance you add to the Items dictionary the same instance you call SaveChanges on?

Comment: Yes it is. There is only one context active